# Run gulp tasks in serial from command line?

Tags: gulp

Is it possible to run gulp tasks in serial from the command line?

For example, so that:

```
$ gulp clean build
```

Will first run `gulp clean` to completion, then `gulp build`?

I emphatically do *not* want to make `clean` a dependency of `build` because I don't want to clean before *every* build.

Answer (score 1):

And what about?

```
$ gulp clean && gulp build
```